# Knockout - custom binding inside `with` tag - how to pass "$root " to custom binding?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a custom binding inside `with` tag

```
<div id="mapContainer" data-bind="with: contentTabs">
  ............
            <div id="map" data-bind="createMap: { }"></div>
  ............
</div>
```

The custom binding is defined as follows

```
ko.bindingHandlers.createMap = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
       //Some code which accesses the viewModel
       ....
    }
}
```

"viewModel" parameter of the custom binding refers to "contentTabs" variable (defined in "with" binding above).

I want to access the view model (root) from the  custom binding in a clean way.

Is it possible?

The code worked well before I wrapped the custom binding by "with" binding.
- how to pass "$root " to custom binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass in that value as an additional binding -

```
<div id="map" data-bind="createMap: { }, createMapOptions: { parentContext: $root.something }"></div>
```

And then in your custom binding get the value of the other bindings -

```
ko.bindingHandlers.createMap = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var options = allBindingsAccessor().createMapOptions;
        var thisContext = options.parentContext;
    }
}
```